# Sum of combinatorial numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't know how to evaluate this sum

$ 
\large{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+n+1 \choose 2k}{2k+n \choose 2k+1}} $.
I have so far this 
$ 
\large{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k+n+1)(2k+1)}{n(n+1)}} = \large{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{4k^2+2kn+4k+n+1}{n(n+1)}} (correct)= \large{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{(2/3)(n(n+1)(2n+1))+n^2(n+1)+2n(n+1)+n+1}{n(n+1)}}$.

>

(not correct) Where I did the mistake? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(2k+1)(2k+n+1)}{n(n+1)}&=&\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)^2 + n\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k+1)\right)\\&=&\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\left(\frac{4n^3+12n^2+11n}{3}+n^3+2n^2\right)\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{7n+11}{3}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$